# How to make concurrent Node.js stream processing while preserving order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, stream

I have a complex data processing pipeline using streams, in which I have a readable stream `input`, a writable stream `output`, and a series of transform streams (let's call them `step1`, `step2`, `step3`, and `step4`). While `step1`, `step3`, and `output` are stateless, relying only on the data chunks coming in to produce their output, chunk for chunk, `step2` and `step4` are aggregation steps, collecting data from multiple chunks to produce their output, and often having outputs that overlap time-wise (e.g. chunk1, chunk3 and chunk5 might produce output1, chunk2 and chunk4 might produce output2, and so on).

Currently, the pipeline is structured as follows:

```
input.pipe(step1).pipe(step2).pipe(step3).pipe(step4).pipe(output);
```

This pipeline is very computationally expensive, and as such **I'd like to split it across multiple instances, preferably running on multiple cores**. Node.js streams guarantee order preservation, so Node.js seems to balance the message passing such that data chunks coming out of one step first get passed into the next step first, and this is a property I'd need to have on whatever method I come up with of making this computation concurrent.

I'm definitely not asking for hand-holding, more if anyone has solved this problem before, and the general approach used for this kind of thing. I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: Not certain what issue is? `.pipe(step2)` should not be reached until `.pipe(step1)` process is completed.

Comment: What is the actual problem which currently exists that you are trying to resolve?

Comment: @guest271314 I'm trying to take a Node.js streamed data processing application, and split it such that different stages can run on different chunks concurrently, preferably across multiple processor cores to increase performance

Comment: Have not tried [node.js implementation of streams](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook), though have tried native streams available at browser which is implemented based on the [specification](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/). How do you currently perform different actions at different processor cores, and receive notification when the procedure completes? What is the issue with the code at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 Unfortunately it would seem you and I are talking about two very different types of streams

Comment: In which ways are the stream implementations of node.js streams and streams standard different?

Answer (score 2):

Although I haven't been able to complete the order preservation, the streaming framework I'm supporting, [scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet), will get you really close to achieve your goal.

I'll nudge you here towards the best solution:

```
let seq = 0;
source.pipe(new DataStream())
    .map(data => {data, itr: seq++})        // mark your order
    .separate(x => x % 8)                   // separate into 8 streams
    .cluster((stream) => {                  // spawn subprocesses
         // do your multi threaded transforms here
    }, {threads: 8})
    .mux((a, b) => a.itr - b.itr)           // merge in the order above
```

At some point I will introduce reordering, but in order to keep abstraction I can't take too many shortcuts, but you can take yours like the 2^52 limitation of count in the above example (seq will run out of bit space to increment then).

This should lead you towards some solution.